# Modify string with `re.sub`

Tags: python, regex

Suppose a string:

```
s = 'F3·Compute·Introduction to Methematical Thinking.pdf'
```

I substitute `F3·Compute·` with `''` using `regex`

```
In [23]: re.sub(r'F3?Compute?', '',s)
Out[23]: 'F3·Compute·Introduction to Methematical Thinking.pdf'
```

It failed to work as I intented

When tried,

```
In [21]: re.sub(r'F3·Compute·', '', 'F3·Compute·Introduction to Methematical Thinking.pdf')
Out[21]: 'Introduction to Methematical Thinking.pdf'
```

What's the problem with my regex pattern?

Comment: what's your desired output? just getting rid of F3.Compute.?

Comment: Use the dot, not the question mark. The dot means 'any char', the question mark means '1 or 0 of whatever char before the question mark'

Comment: F3?C, only match F3C or FC

Answer (score -1):

Use dot to match any single character:

```
#coding: utf-8
import re

s = 'F3·Compute·Introduction to Methematical Thinking.pdf'
output = re.sub(r'F3.Compute.', '', unicode(s,"utf-8"), flags=re.U)
print output
```

Your original pattern, `'F3?Compute?` was not having the desired effect.  This said to match `F` followed by the number `3` optionally.  Also, you made the final `e` of `Compute` optional.  In any case, you were not accounting for the separator characters.

Note also that we must match on the `unicode` version of the string, and not the string directly.  Without doing this, a dot won't match the unicode separator which you are trying to target.  Have a look at the demo below for more information.

### Demo

Answer (score -1):

The question mark `?` does not stand in for a single character in regular expressions. It means 0 or 1 of the *previous* character, which in your case was `3` and `e`. Instead, the `.` is what you're looking for. It is a wildcard that stands for a single character (and has nothing to do with your middle-dot character; that is just coincidence).

```
re.sub(r'F3.Compute.', '',s)
```